# dynamic programming: longest palindromic subsequence, recurrence relation question

Tags: dynamic-programming

[image: excel table]
Moving from top left down the column then over to the right column, taking ideas from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-palindromic-subsequence-dp-12/
I want to restate the question at the top of the Excel table.
Why do I need to max from T(i,j-1) and T(i+1,j)?  Can't you just take what's in T(i,j-1)?
I changed the input slightly and I still get the right answer just taking T(i,j-1) when T(i,0) != T(0,j)

Edited:

[image: excel2]

A counterexample would be nice to see.

Comment: "just taking T(i,j-1) when T(i,0) != T(0,j)". The part "when T(i,0) != T(0,j)" does not make sense to me. Do you mean "just taking T(i,j-1) when X(i) != X(j)"? Here X is the original array.

Comment: yes, I put the original array in the 0th row and 0th column like I saw for a sequence alignment DP problem, Needleman-Wunsch algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Let `T(i,j) = T(i,j-1)` when `L(i) != L(j)`

You could be wrong if you take `T[0, n-1]` as the final answer as in [the article on GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-palindromic-subsequence-dp-12/). For example, let `X = "abb"`. Then `T[0, n-1] = 1` while the longest palindromic subsequence is `bb` with length 2.

You are right if you take the maximum of `T[i,n-1]` as the final answer, where `i` goes through all valid indices, i.e., from `0` to `n-1` and `n` is the length of the given string `X`.

What is happening?

We need to understand/specify the meaning of `T(i,j)`. We can let `T(i,j)` denote the length of the longest one among all subsequences that **start at index `i` and end no later than index `j`**, where `i <= j`. Then it is correct that `T(i,j) = T(i,j-1)` when `X(i) != X(j)`, since any palindromic subsequence that start at index `i` cannot end at index `j`, i.e., it must end no later than index `j-1`.

#### Exercise

1. Describe the meaning of `L(i,j)` in that GeeksforGeeks article.
2. Suppose we let `T(i,j)` denote the length of the longest one among all subsequences that **start at index `i` and end at index `j`**, where `i <= j`.

   - What will be the recurrence relations?
   - Suppose we have computed all `T(i,j)`. What would be the final answer, i.e., the length of the longest palindromic subsequence overall?

Comment: L(i,j) is the length of the longest palindromic subsequence from i to j and thus I need to take either max, I get it upon trying out your toy counterexample.  Thank you so much!